# Spring cloud app error in aws ecs environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, aws-ecs

The following is the problem description:

1. This error is only generated when the service is deployed on AWS ECS, there is no error in the local environment
2. Every microservice currently deployed will have this problem. This problem will not affect normal functions. The time of occurrence is also random.
3. The current spring cloud version is Dalston.SR4.

Here is the error log：

```
2018-06-03 21:20:09.436-04:00 ERROR 14 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse   A message body reader for Java class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and Java type class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo, and MIME media type text/html was not found


2018-06-03 21:20:09.438-04:00 ERROR 14 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse   The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
```